# Is it possible to add a Body and and Files to a single Axios request in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

So I am able to send either a file or a body with the POST request below, but how can I send both ?

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/upload", formData )
```

how can I add something to the **body:{}** section ?

Server response:

```
  files: {
        myFile: {
          name: 'close.bmp',
          data: <Buffer 42 4d 98 cb 01 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 c8 00 00 00 c4 00 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 62 cb 01 00 c3 0e 00 00 c3 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 117606 more bytes>,
          size: 117656,
          encoding: '7bit',
          tempFilePath: '',
          truncated: false,
          mimetype: 'image/bmp',
          md5: '8860ffe0891f5142164ea21b092c3996',
          mv: [Function: mv]
        }
      },
      body: {},
      route: Route {
        path: '/upload',
        stack: [ [Layer] ],
        methods: { post: true }
      },
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Node on the backend?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with `express-fileupload`. So install it and have the app use it in your Node server:

```
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

app.use(fileUpload());
```

Then in your front end, create a `FormData` object and append the file and any other properties to it:

```
const upload = (file, description) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('description', description);

    return axios.post('/upload', data);
};
```

Then in your route you can access the file under the `files` propery, and the others under the `body` property:

```
function upload (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body.description);
    return res.status(200).end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. 
data.append('description', description); is what I was missing !